# add /remove "selected" or any other value to .toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, attr

I have a button that i toggle to show active / not active icon. (by changing  the icon)
But i want to also to add /remove "selected" or any other value to this toggle.

```
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa fa-check-square fa fa-check-circle-o');   
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: You are missing the last `});`

Comment: yes but the question is - how I add / remove "selected" value to this toggle

Comment: Sidenote: Putting `fa` in there twice means you'll toggle it both on and off in the same call. If this is what you want, it can just as well be achieved by not toggling that class at all: `.toggleClass('fa-check-square fa-check-circle')`

Comment: It's not clear what you need by "selected" value. Is that just another class on the `i`? If so, simply add it to the toggle: `.toggleClass('fa-check-square fa-check-circle selected')`.

Comment: i would like to combine this toggle with something like this : $('.test').attr('selected', 'selected');​

Comment: Something like this? `$('.test').prop('selected', !$('.test').prop('selected') )`?

Comment: Thanks David! I got your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy you have done everything just one more line to add. And your new code should look like :

```
$(function() {
$('#button').click(function() {
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa fa-check-square fa fa-check-circle-o');     
if ($(this).val() == "selected")
   $(this).val("select")
else
   $(this).val("selected");
});
```